# UV space and stacking UV's on top of each other to share the same texture

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, packed-data

Coming from MODO, I'm playing with Nodes and the UV editor. Strange thing I made a UV of a simple side of a cube (a square) but when I imported the image the UV stretched to fit the image. In MODO it was the image that scaled not the UV. So why did the UV stretch to fit the image and result in a distorted image? Yes I can scale the UV back but it's a bit of a guessing gain to remove distortion.

Also how can you stack UV islands so they are packed on top of each other as I want to same image to be tiled over 9 separate faces on this Rubik's Cube I'm playing with. In MODO you could stack them on top of each other. I managed to do this by accident when 'J' joining all the objects after making the UV but I was wondering if there's a Pack option for after-the-fact.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66727/whats-the-meaning-of-0-to-1-space-in-uv

Comment: if, in the Node Editor, you create an Image Texture node, then load the picture in this node, and unwrap your object again, then the UV will keep its correct size

Comment: can I stack the UV's on top of each other with a Pack option (like in MODO) so the faces share the same Texture?

Comment: yes, if you do a simple Unwrap, by default the faces will overlay

Comment: OK thank you... it's just all a bit strange since MODO

Comment: What I said was not completely correct, it works for one face but not for the complete cube, if you a do simple unwrap of the whole cube it won't work, it will stretch, you have to use another unwrap method (Cube Projection, Smart UV Project) or Mark Seam and Unwrap, or upload a square picture. Sometimes I don't completely understand the logic of Blender, I would have expected that it works like you explained.