# Creating a Model That Fits a 64x64 Pixel Texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I want to make a model similar to the *Minecraft* one but with more joints. Every body part is a separate object with it's own material, texture and UV. What I did first was create a model for the the body, assigned all the seams and generated the UV on a **64x64** image and then I exported the *UV Layout*, put it in a program and just marked the corners to check if it works, exported it in **1024x1024 pixels** because otherwise it is really blurry and when I put it on the body it was offset by half a pixel on the **64x64** image *(this was much more on the **1024x1024** of course)*. How would I calculate the size needed for it not to offset?

**P.S.** I don't have any images since it got me really mad after I remade the thing 10 times so I just deleted it...

Comment: UV maps can be scaled in all direction. You can even constraint the islands to the bounds to quickly adapt the map to the texture. Changing the map resolution is usually not a big deal because UV span from 0to1, regardless the texture size. Could you better explain where exactly are you stuck and why?

Comment: My problem is that the UV doesn't correctly cover the image even tho I draw over the UV Layout I export. I need to find the correct aspect ratio for the size of the object

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66727/whats-the-meaning-of-0-to-1-space-in-uv

Comment: That isn't my problem! I get it, I didn't know that UVs work like that but it doesn't change a thing, but I want to create a 64x64 texture that fits onto my 6 sided object correctly