# UV unwrapping to rectangular image

Tags: mesh, uv

I'm using rectangular image, as that makes it easier for the game to read texture overlap. But whenever i unwrap a mesh, it gets stretched along longer side. So even a cube with square faces gets its faces as rectangular on UV.
Scaling back to 1 doesn't do anything as i can create even an absolutely new cube mesh and it does the same silly thing.

Apart from manual adjuststing (scaling) on y-axis (usually it's y-axis), is there any other way to prevent this from hapenning at all? It's still easy if i have that image say 500pixels on 1000 pixels - i've got to type in 0.5 each time when scaling down a bunch of UV faces. But that's not the point here.

Edit: Thought that would have been self explanatory, sorry - here is a  screenshot.
[image]

Comment: One the operator panel, after the unwrap, uncheck "correct aspect".  Does that do what you want?

Comment: could you please share your blend file or add screenshots with shader nodes + all relevant settings so we can check it out?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66727/whats-the-meaning-of-0-to-1-space-in-uv

Comment: @Nathan - that "correct aspect" option does absolutely nothing haha... It's possibly useful in other cases but not in this one. I thought about it before, tried it again in case i missed something but it doesn't work here at all.

Comment: @Chris - here is a screenshot added. Not sure where I should get settings from. Unless all you need is in that screenshot.

Comment: @macluk I guess you understand the "correct aspect" wrong. If you read the answer that Duarte has linked to, in UV space (0, 0) is the lower left corner and (1, 1) is the upper right corner. So (0, 0) is 0% of the UV space in X and Y direction while (1, 1) is 100% in X and Y direction. Every image that you are using is mapped like this. In your case, if you are using a rectangle picture e.g. 2000 pixels wide and 1000 pixels high, and the face you unwrap is 10 m x 10 m, than it's "correct aspect" is 1:1, so to fill the UV map this would mean 100% wide, 100% high = 2000 x 1000 pixels.

Comment: @macluk You unwrap with the rectangular image in the background of the _UV Editor_, right? Or do you have a material on the object you're unwrapping, with an _Image Texture Node_? Because to "ignore" the rectangular shape of the image, the unwrapped object needs to have a material containg that image texture assigned to the corresponding faces.