# How can I find the resolution/format of a face when UV unrwapping?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I am trying to create an image as a mask for texture painting. Im still a beginner when it comes to texture painting, so what I want to do is assign this mixed material to only 1 face of my mesh and then create an image with the resolution of that particular face. How do I find that info?

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way but you can export the UV layout (in the UV Editor > UV > Export UV Layout) and open it with an image editor like Photoshop or Krita

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66727/whats-the-meaning-of-0-to-1-space-in-uv